# Could not load file '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo' when I use ifdown or ifup

Tags: centos, ifconfig

When using `ifdown` or `ifup` for the `lookback` interface in CentOS 7:

```
[root@localhost etc]# ifup lo
```

I have got the error below:

> Could not load file '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo'
>   Could not load file '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo'
>   Could not load file '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo'
>   Could not load file '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo'

However if I use the `ifconfig` command, it shows the command(`ifdown` or `ifup`) works with success.

---

As I tested, the use of the `ifconfig lo up/down` does not show any signs of errors.

What is happening?

---

**EDIT**

I checked the `ifcfg-lo` file, it shows the info below:

```
[root@localhost etc]# ls -la /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 254 Jun 26 20:07 /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo
```

Comment: ifconfig does not use network-scripts ; please edit the question and add to it the output of  `ls -la /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo`

Comment: Does chmod a+rx /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo correct the situation?  (probably not, I suspect it must be something with selinux...)

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro it still reports the error. and in the front, I tells it even reports the mentioned error but the command works.

Comment: Or the command appears to work. I am sure, I do not use selinux, someone else will hopefully help you.

Answer (score 1):

First of all stop Using ifconfig command anymore with Centos 7 version and later versions because it doesnt give you full information about your network card parameters (For example if you assigened 2 IP addresses to your Card)
instead use ipa command or ip addr show command.
Second This problem is currently being tracked as a bug by Red Hat.
To Fix this problem: Add NM_CONTROLLED=no to /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo.
Root Cause: ifcfg-rh plugin in NetworkManager does not support loopback interface type and logs a message about it in system log.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fully resolve this issues, update to higher version.
And in current version you can fix it by adding "NM_CONTROLLED=no" to /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo configuration file, then restart the network following this link https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1549693

Comment: Please add some details from the external webpage in your answer, using the page as a reference rather than the primary resource.